# Split records based on a space or a tab using csvreader

Tags: python, csv

I have a record file an example record looks like this:

```
122792 2014-07-26   1672
```

The first two records are separated by space the second two by a tab space. How can I make the csvreader read all three column?
I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters= [' ','\t'])
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
    for row in reader:
        print row
OUTPUT:
['122792 2014-07-26', '1672']
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Well I only mean the last two and the first two :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example data, you don't need to be using the `csv` module here, instead use `str.split` which will split on all whitespace (space and tabs for instance):

```
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    rows = (line.split() for line in fin)
    for row in rows:
        print row
```

If as mentioned you will have multiple delimiter characters, then it's possible to change the generator function to be:

```
rows = (re.split('[ \t,;]+', line) for line in fin)
```

Which uses a regular expression to split on either a space, tab, comma or semicolon, eg:

```
re.split('[ \t,;]+', 'a   b;d;e     \tfff,ghj')
# ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'fff', 'ghj']
```

Comment: I need that for a separate reason. I needed to dump it to a database. I am doing string.split right now but then I need to push it to the DB line by line.

Comment: @Sohaib okay... well, if this approach works for you, you can do whatever you need to do with each `row`...

Comment: Thing is I have no control over the input coming. It is dumped on an online store and I pick it up from there and further process it. If say in the future the file started coming in with semicolons or commas with two more columns I need to just add the delimiters to the sniffer object. That way I wouldn't have to restructure much if such a thing happens. For now I had already been using the string split :)

Comment: @Sohaib `csv.reader` doesn't support multiple field delimiters - even though you provide delimiters to the `Sniffer` object, the sniff will return the most common delimiter and apply that single character delimiter for parsing. Your other option *might* be using `re.split('[ \t,;]+', line)` (or whatever delimiters) there are... eg: `re.split('[ \t,;]+', 'a   b;d;e     \tfff,ghj')` gives `['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'fff', 'ghj']`

Comment: @Sohaib be aware though that if you're receiving text fields `"Like this one, with a comma in it; oh dear - semicolon as well!"` where those characters shouldn't act like delimiters... you've got another issue to content with :)

Comment: Its mostly statistical it won't happen that way probably. Thanks a lot for the help!! Add your other comment to the answer so I can mark it as correct :)